# Как добавлять несколько элементов с помощью append?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку каждый раз появлялся новый элемент списка, но все ограничивается на одном разе, в чем проблема?

```js
let addbutton = document.querySelector('.AddButton');
let li = document.createElement('li');
let ol = document.querySelector('.ol');
li.innerHTML = 'element of list';
li.className = 'elem';

addbutton.onclick = function(){
    ol.append(li) 
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body{
    background-color: #3b3b3b;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.ToDoBox{
    width: 385px;
    height: 625px;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    margin-top: 120px;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}

.AddButton{
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin-left: 10px; 
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #363636;
    border: 0px;
}

.AddButton:active{
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
}

.elem{
    color: white;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ToDo List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="ToDoBox">
        <button class="AddButton">+</button>
        <ol class="ol">
            
        </ol>
    </div>

    <script src="javas.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется, что все дело лишь в том, что надо создавать новый экземпляр `li` **при каждом** нажатии.

```
addbutton.onclick = function(){
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = 'element of list';
    li.className = 'elem';
    ol.append(li) 
}
```